# How to add non-unique elements to existing array in Firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, time-series

I am using Firestore to store time series data being pulled from a sensor.  I am using Python to push the data, namely the Firebase-Admin package for verification.  I chose to store this data using arrays, where each index corresponds with an array across different fields. Is there a way to add non-unique elements to the array? Or can arrays only store unique elements? If so, what data structure would you suggest for storing time series data.

I am trying to add observations to an existing array in Firestore, but ArrayUpdate only adds the element if it is not already present in the array. When I execute the second chuck of code (to update the existing array), only unique values are saved

```
# Initialize arrays and push to Firestore
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import datetime

cred = credentials.Certificate('path_to_certificate')

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
cell_1_arr = []
cell_2_arr = []
cell_3_arr = []
exec_time_arr = []
curr_time_arr = []
pred_volt = 12562.70
meas_volt = 12362.70
current = 0.0
soc = 0,0
cell_1_volt = 4.32
cell_2_volt = 4.4
cell_3_volt = 4.23
exec_time = 0.4
curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
pred_v_arr.append(pred_volt)
meas_v_arr.append(meas_volt)
c_arr.append(current)
soc_arr.append(soc)
cell_1_arr.append(cell_1_volt)
cell_2_arr.append(cell_2_volt)
cell_3_arr.append(cell_3_volt)
exec_time_arr.append(exec_time)
curr_time_arr.append(curr_time)

try:
    push_data = {
        u'time': curr_time_arr,
        u'vpred': meas_v_arr,
        u'vmeas': pred_v_arr,
        u'current': c_arr,
        u'soc': soc_arr,
        u'cell1': cell_1_arr,
        u'cell2': cell_2_arr,
        u'cell3': cell_3_arr,
        u'exectime': exec_time_arr
    }
    db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").set(push_data)

# Add add a new observation to the different arrays
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'time': firestore.ArrayUnion(curr_time_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'vpred': firestore.ArrayUnion(pred_v_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'vmeas': firestore.ArrayUnion(meas_v_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'current': firestore.ArrayUnion(c_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'cell1': firestore.ArrayUnion(cell_1_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'cell2': firestore.ArrayUnion(cell_2_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'cell3': firestore.ArrayUnion(cell_3_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'exectime': firestore.ArrayUnion(exec_time_arr)})
db.collection(u'battery1').document(u"day1").update({'soc': firestore.ArrayUnion(soc_arr)})
```

[image: firestore screenshot 1]

In the screenshot above you can see that there are 8 elements in the "time" field (as all calls to datetime.now() produce unique instances of timestamps), while all the other fields have only saved the unique data points sent (exectime/soc only have two data points, for 8 calls to ArrayUnion).

Answer (score 3):

When you use `firestore.ArrayUnion` that operator's job is literally to ensure each value can only be present once in the array.

If you want to allow non-unique values, don't use `firestore.ArrayUnion` but just add the elements to the array regularly. This does require that you read the entire document and array first, then add the element locally, and write the result back.